# Can we extend element plus 'El Tree' component(build with compsition api) to our custom component and use their props?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, element-plus

I am new to vue3, in vue 2 version the "element-ui" uses the "option API" on "ElTree" component so that I can able to extend the 'ElTree' in my custom component and access 'ElTree' props like 'root, dragState'. But now the 'element-plus' library uses the "composition API" so I couldn't able to extend the "ElTree" and access the props 'root, dragState'.

What should I do now?
Can I able to extend the "ElTree" component or do I have to use the 'ElTree' component directly from the 'element-plus'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can imagine that I want to extend the `el-table` to create a new component named XTable and use its `props.data`

```
//XTable.vue
<template>
    <el-table
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :data="formatedData"
    >
      <template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
        <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope || {}" />
      </template>
    </el-table>
  </template>
  
  <script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ElTable } from "element-plus";
  
  const props = defineProps({
    data: { type: Array<any>, required: true },
  });
  
  const formatedData = computed(()=>{
    return data.map(...)
  })
  </script>
```

- Extend component's props: use `v-bind="$attrs"` to pass all attributes from `<xtable>` to `<el-table>`.
- Extend component's slots: use `<template v-for...` to fallthrough slots.
- Use their props: define same prop name `data` for `XTable`，and pass a formatted one to `el-table`.Since `$attrs` object (in Vue3) includes all attributes that not declared by the component's prop or emits options(e.g., class, style, etc), you should manually define in `XTable` and pass it to `el-table`